# Software Paradigm for Pushing Data Through a System

Tags: python, software-design

**tl-dr:  I wanted you feedback if the correct software design pattern to use would be a Push/Pull Pipeline pattern.**

Details:
Let's say I have several software algorithms/blocks which process data coming into a software system:

```
[Download Data] --> [Pre Process Data] --> [ML Classification] --> [Post Results]
```

The download data block simply loiters until midnight when new data is available and then downloads new data.  The pre-process data simply loiters until newly available downloaded data is present, and then preprocesses the data.  The Machine Learning (ML) Classification block simply loiters until new data is available to classify, etc.

The entire system seems to be event driven and I think fits the push/pull paradigm perfectly?

The [Download Data] block would be a producer?  The consumers would be all the subsequent blocks with the exception of the [Plot Results] which would be a results collector?

```
Producer = pull
Consumer = pull then push
result collector = pull
```

I'm working within a python framework.  This implementation looked ideal:
https://learning-0mq-with-pyzmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyzmq/patterns/pushpull.html
https://github.com/ashishrv/pyzmqnotes

[Push/Pull Pipeline Pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wdTe.png)

I'm totally open to using another software paradigm other than push/pull if I've missed the mark here.  I'm also open to using another repo as well.

Thanks in advance for your help with the above!

Comment: Is your pipeline going to stay this linear or become more branched? Because if it’s the former, I think what you’re suggesting is just overkill.

Comment: this is very broad topic. having said that, push/pull is useful pattern for messaging i.e. small data transfer like signaling that a job has been done. your usecase sounds like a typical data/workflow pipeline and we have many existing solutions for that like https://github.com/spotify/luigi and https://github.com/apache/airflow. use them if you can and avoid reinventing the wheel. if not just have a look to get better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I've done similar pipelines many many times and very much like to break it into blocks like that.  Why?  Mainly for automatic recovery from any errors.  If something gets delayed, it will auto recover next hour.  If something needs to be fixed mid-pipeline, fix it and name it so it gets picked up next cycle.  (That and the fact smaller blocks are easier to design, build, and test).

For example, your `[Download Data]` should run every hour to look for waiting data: if none, go back to sleep; if some, download it to a file with a name containing a timestamp and state: `2020-0103T2153.downloaded.json`.  `[Pre Process Data]` should run every hour to look for files named `*.downloaded.json`: if none, go back to sleep; if one or more, pre-processes each in increasing timestamp order with output to `<same-timestamp>.pre-processed.json`.  Etc, etc for each step.

Doing it this way meant may unplanned events auto recovered and nobody would know unless they looked in the log files (you should log each so you know what happened).  Easy to sleep at night :)

In these scenarios, the event driving this is just time-of-day via crontab.  When "awoken", each step in the pipeline just looks to see if it has any work waiting for it.  Trying to make the file-creation event initiate things was non-simple especially if you need to re-initiate things (would need to re-create the file).

I wouldn't use a message queue as that's more complicated and more suited when you have to handle incoming messages as they arrive.  Your case is more simple batch file processing so keep it simple and sleep at night.